# How to add a span after a symbol in my text using jquery

Tags: jquery

i have element

```
<h1>some text - subtitle starts here</h1>
```

i want to add a span after -

```
<h1>Some text - <span>subtitle starts here</span></h1>
```

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('h1').append('<span>subtitle part</span>');
```

Or if you have the subtitle part in there and just want to wrap with `<span>`:

```
var text = $('h1').text();
text = text.split(' - ');
$('h1').html(text[0] + ' - <span>' + text[1] + '</span>');
```

Comment: This is not what OP want

Answer (score 2):

You can do `split` with hyphen and change the second part of the split array. Then, `join` using hyphen. Assign this new result as a HTML to `<h1>` tag:

```js
var nHTML = $('h1').html();
nHTML = nHTML.split('-');
nHTML[1] = '<span>' + nHTML[1] + '</span>';
$('h1').html(nHTML.join('-'));
```

```css
h1 span{
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>some text - subtitle starts here</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one `h1` tag on website you can use `replaceWith` function

```
$("h1").replaceWith("<h1>Some text - <span>subtitle starts here</span></h1>");
```

Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/

Answer (score -1):

You need the `append()` function. (See documentiation [here](http://api.jquery.com/append/))

Html:
    `<h1 id="foo">Loremipsum</h1>`

jQuery:

```
$('#foo').append('<span>subtitle starts here</span>');
```

Comment: This is not what OP want –

Comment: Oops sorry, that's correct. Wasn't clear at first sight.